# How to declare map with types of user type properties

Tags: kotlin

I have a custom type declared as:

```kotlin
data class User (
    val name: String,
    val rank: Int
)
```

and wish to declare a Map whose keys are the name and values are the ranks, referring to the types as declared for User.

I have tried kotlin reflection,

```kotlin
val foo1 = Map <User::name, User::rank>()   //compiler error 'not enough information to infer type...'
```

Is there a normative way to do this?

So far, I "just have to know" the types for key and value, e.g:

```kotlin
val foo = Map <String, Int>()
```

But this is brittle, and would break if I change User in the future, e.g `.rank` from Int to Float.  Of course, I wouldn't remain ignorant of my oversight for long, I expect the compiler would start complaining, but is there something elegant I can do now?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [value class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html) to define the user's name and rank.

```kotlin
@JvmInline
value class UserName(val name: String)

@JvmInline
value class UserRank(val rank: Int)

data class User (
    val name: UserName,
    val rank: UserRank,
)

val userMap = Map<UserName, UserRank>() // type-safe map
```

Or create a value class that implements `Map<String, Int>`, and use [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html#inline-classes-and-delegation).

```kotlin
@JvmInline
value class UserMap(
  private val map: Map<String, Int>
) : Map<String, Int> by map {

  operator fun contains(user: User): Boolean = 
    map[user.name] == user.rank
}
```

Or both together!

Comment: That is another way to write the code, but not the kind of solution I was looking for.  I'd like to know whether there's a way to declare a variable whose type is the same as some other, already defined, variable.